# Обработка щелчка на элементе меню

Tags: javascript, html, click, onclicklistener

Как задать обработку щелчка на элементе меню с определенным id в js файле?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('SOME_ID').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // какая-то логика
});
```

или

```
document.querySelector('#SOME_ID').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // какая-то логика
});
```